# External library variable not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to include a javascript library (WaveSurfer) into my Angular app (Using Mean.io). 
The problem is a warning appears into the console each time I run `grunt` :

> In packages\tracks\public\services\tracks.js : 
>   **'WaveSurfer' is not defined.**

Here is the code of my different files:

**public/controllers/tracks.js**

```
angular.module('mean').controller('PlayerController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'Tracks','myWaveSurfer',
function($scope, Global,Tracks, myWaveSurfer) {
    $scope.global = Global;

    //Player WaveSurfer
    var wavesurfer = Object.create(myWaveSurfer);
    wavesurfer.load('music.mp3');
```

**public/services/tracks.js**

```
angular.module('mean.tracks').factory('myWaveSurfer', function() {
    return WaveSurfer; /*Warning here*/
});
```

The content of the **wavesurfer.min.js** looks like :

```
var WaveSurfer = {
   defaultParams: {...}
   init: function(params) {...}
   ...
}
```

I included correctly the library into `config/assets.json` so the library can be loaded.
I can see it on the Chrome console :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/wavesurfer.js/build/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
```

It only works with `grunt --force` but is there a solution to include properly this library without warning ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hard to tell from what you pasted, but is this an error coming from jshint/jslint? In that case you should be able to declare WaveSurfer as a global in the gruntfile.

Comment: Thanks you @ivarni ! I just added `/* global WaveSurfer: true */` on the top of my services/tracks.js and the warning disappears. Thanks you again ! It is a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are inside the Node env.

Add this to your globals:

```
GLOBAL.WaveSurfer = {};
```

Or you could pull it in with `require`

```
GLOBAL.WaveSurfer = require('...');
```

If you `require` make sure the library `module.exports` the global object.